# Load Java Class File To Oracle Database

Tags: java, oracle11g, loadjava

I have some java classes and i want to import these files into oracle database 11gR2 .
When i want to use loadjava utility , the error in below is shown :

```
 C:\Users\oracle>loadjava -f -v -r -user tree AllData.class

Password:
*******
arguments: '-user' 'tree' '-f' '-v' '-r' 'AllData.class'
Error while opening file: AllData.class
    Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: AllData.class (The system cannot fi
nd the file specified)
creating :  AllData.class
The following operations failed

     AllData.class: opening file
exiting  : Failures occurred during processing
```

My java class in this destination :

```
C:\Users\oracle\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication1\src\javaapplication1
```

Can any one help me how to handle this error ?
Thanks

Comment: Why not providing the path to the file? The exception is clear to me.